# How to properly play a WAV file by constructing an AudioBuffer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, wav, audiobuffer

I am struggling to play [this WAV file](http://f.cl.ly/items/0i2d2i281V1k0m191z2y/test.wav), which plays in VLC (according to which it is a `Mono`, `IMA WAV APDCM Audio (ms)` file sampled at `24000Hz` with `16 bits per sample`).

I suspect that there is something wrong with the WAV file itself, since when I try to play it by embedding it directly *via* `<audio>`, the play button is inactive…when I try to play it programmatically using `new Audio()`, I get the error `Failed to load because no supported source was found.`

Here is the simplest example of what I've tried which produces *some* sound…other attempts I've tried which attempt to use `AudioContext.decodeAudioData` all choke on loading the audio, throwing `Unable to decode audio data`.

This example produces some, somewhat recognizable sound, but I'm clearly doing something wrong because it is so scratchy— My understanding is that `AudioBuffer` requires a `Float32Array` whose values fall between `[-1,1]`, which these don't.  But I don't know how to normalize them, since many of the values are on the order of `10e32`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    var context = new AudioContext();

    function loadSound(url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.responseType = "arraybuffer";


        request.onload = function() {
            data = new Uint8Array(request.response);

            var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, data.length, 24000);

            var channelData = buffer.getChannelData(0);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                channelData[i] = data[i];
            }

            var source = context.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = buffer;
            source.connect(context.destination);
            source.start(0);
        }

        request.send();
    }

    loadSound('./test.wav');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated; thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In [this `phosphorous` issue](https://github.com/nathan/phosphorus/issues/494) I found a suitable answer in the `readADPCM` and `encodeAudio16bit` function reading a `UInt8Array` and encoding 16 bit audio.

Comment: This answer should contain a code sample of the relevant code that lead the OP to select this as the appropriate answer

Comment: The link above is broken :(